# Combining 3 SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 SQL Queries. The output that I needed is the role, eid, target, coacheename, total exemptions and total coach. However I am having a hard time combining my 3 queries.

My first query:

```
SELECT
    coachEID, role, coacheeEID, 
    IIF(COUNT(status) > IIF(a.role = 'SME', 1, 2), IIF(a.role = 'SME', 1, 2), COUNT(status)) AS total 
FROM 
    coaching z
JOIN
    tbl_calendar v ON z.starttime BETWEEN v.datestart AND v.dateend
JOIN
    roster a ON z.coachEID = a.EID
WHERE 
    z.status = 'completed'
    AND v.month = '1' AND v.year = '2017'
    AND a.location = 'manila'
GROUP BY
    coacheid, coacheeeid, status, role
```

The second query is:

```
SELECT 
    y.role, y.eid, IIF(y.sme = y.eid, 1, 2) AS target
FROM 
    roster y
JOIN 
    roster x ON (x.supervisor = y.eid OR x.sme = y.eid OR x.teamlead = y.eid) 
             AND x.eid <> y.eid 
             AND x.employstatus = 'Active'
WHERE 
    y.employstatus = 'active' 
    AND y.Role IN ('SME', 'Junior Team Lead','Team Lead', 'Shift Lead', 
                   'Operations Lead', 'Quality Lead', 'Policy Lead') 
    AND y.location = 'manila'
```

The third query is:

```
SELECT 
    x.coachEID, x.CoacheeEID, SUM(x.NoOfApproved) AS exempt, 
    x.month, x.year 
FROM
    exemptitems x
LEFT JOIN
    roster y ON y.eid = x.Coacheid
WHERE
    x.month = '1' AND x.year = '2017'
    AND y.eid = x.coacheid 
    AND x.NoOfApproved IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    x.CoachEID, x.CoacheeEID, x.Month, x.year
```

[Result of queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev4ss.png)

Comment: And the combined result? (Formatted text please.)

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Place each query into a CTE, CTE1,CTE2,CTE3, and use those CTE's to join to each other based on the common column which appears to be CoachEID.
Better would be to take the common tables from each query and re-write it as a single query.

Comment: the result should be the role, eid, target, coacheename, total exemption and total coach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should be something along the lines of :

```
with CTE1 as (
    select coachEID,role,coacheeEID, IIF(count(status)>IIF(a.role='SME',1,2),IIF(a.role='SME',1,2),count(status))
        as total from coaching z
        join tbl_calendar v
        ON z.starttime BETWEEN v.datestart and v.dateend
        join roster a on z.coachEID=a.EID
        where z.status='completed'
        and v.month='1' and v.year='2017'
        and a.location='manila'
        group by coacheid, coacheeeid, status, role
), CTE2 as (
    SELECT y.role, y.eid, IIF(y.sme=y.eid,1,2) AS target
        FROM roster y
        JOIN roster x ON (x.supervisor = y.eid OR x.sme = y.eid OR x.teamlead = y.eid) AND x.eid <> y.eid 
        AND x.employstatus = 'Active'
        WHERE y.employstatus = 'active' 
        AND y.Role IN ('SME', 'Junior Team Lead','Team Lead', 'Shift Lead', 'Operations Lead', 'Quality Lead', 'Policy Lead') 
        AND y.location = 'manila'
), CTE3 as (
        SELECT x.coachEID,x.CoacheeEID,  sum (x.NoOfApproved) as exempt, x.month, x.year from exemptitems x
        left join roster y on y.eid=x.Coacheid
        where x.month='1' and x.year='2017'
        and y.eid=x.coacheid and x.NoOfApproved is not NULL
        group by x.CoachEID, x.CoacheeEID, x.Month, x.year
)
select c1.role, c2.eid, c2.target, c1.total -- insert the rest of the fields you want to be included
from CTE1 c1
join CTE2 c2 on c1.coachEID = c2.eid
join CTE3 c3 on c1.coachEID = c3.coachEID
```

Please just add the necessary columns in the bottom of the script, as I was not able to understand your request clearly.

Comment: thanks, this helped me. I'm almost getting there :)

Answer (score 0):

You can union each query if the number of columns is the same.  If you need to, you can pad the other queries with literals to provide the same structure on each statement, then just put a UNION between each one.